# Unable to use ApacheCommons for fileupload if I annotate the servlet with MultipartConfig

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, upload, apache-commons

If I annotate the following servlet with `@MultipartConfig` ,I am unable to use `Apache common upload` .

```
@MultipartConfig

public class SendTheFileName extends HttpServlet {
  // something
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
           moveToSharedDirectory(request,path); // call to upload
  }
}
```

For example :

```
public boolean moveToSharedDirectory(HttpServletRequest request,String path) {
    System.out.println("1. OUTSIDE THE TRY BLOCK OF UPLOAD CLASS");
    try {
       System.out.println("2. IN THE TRY BLOCK OF UPLOAD CLASS");
       boolean isMultipart = ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request);
       System.out.println("3. AFTER THE BOOLEAN STATEMENT " + isMultipart);
       if(!isMultipart) {
           // Error:File cannot be uploaded
           System.out.println("Message : IS NOT MULTIPART");
       } else {
           DiskFileItemFactory dfif = new DiskFileItemFactory();
           ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(dfif);
           List list = null;
           list = fileUpload.parseRequest(request); // returns a list of FileItem instances parsed from the request
           Iterator iterator = list.iterator();
           System.out.println("4. JUST BEFORE ENTERING THE WHILE LOOP");
           System.out.println("5. CHECKING IF THE ITERATION HAS ANY ELEMENT : " + iterator.hasNext());

           // ... some more here {-}
         }
    } // close catch
}
```

The statement in the just above snippet :

```
System.out.println("5. CHECKING IF THE ITERATION HAS ANY ELEMENT : " + iterator.hasNext());
```

prints `false`! Why is that ?

If I remove the annotation I get `true` and am able to upload the file.

*Corresponding HTML :*

```
<form method="post" action="SendTheFileName" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div id="Files_to_be_shared"> 
                      <input type="file" id="File" name="FileTag" />
                      <input type="submit" value="Share" /> 
                    </div>
 </form>
```

*Note: For some reason I had to use apache commons to upload the file.*

Comment: Which application server / servlet container do you use?

Comment: @PhilippeMarschall tomcat 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@MultipartConfig` triggers Servlet 3.0 builtin `multipart/form-data` request body parsing right before the servlet's `service()` is invoked. So the Apache Commons FileUpload would face an empty request body when it's its turn to parse the request. In other words, you can't mix them. It does also not make any sense to mix them as they both do exactly same job under the covers.

You have 2 options:

1. Remove `@MultipartConfig` and keep Apache Commons FileUpload.
2. Or, keep `@MultipartConfig` and remove Apache Commons FileUpload.

#### See also:

- [How to upload files to server using JSP/Servlet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824) - shows how to get the parts using Servlet 3.0

Comment: I understood, that we cannot mix both but I didn't understand why the apache commons fileupload will get an empty request body ?

Comment: Because `@MultipartConfig` has already parsed it. Visualize the request body as an `InputStream`. Once you've read it fully, you cannot read it for a second time anymore. You need to create a new one. In other words, to achieve what you want, the enduser has basically to send the same HTTP request twice if you want to parse it twice. And that just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay.Understood it now.Thanks

Comment: commons-fileupload won't work with the JakartaEE as from version 5.0 as the javax.servlet package is gone, compare:
https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/
https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/5.0/apidocs/

Comment: @LukaszLenart: Correct. Just use Servlet API native file upload functionality. It was available since 2009 already. See also the "See also" link in bottom of this answer.