# List<FileItem> is empty after upgrading to java ee 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, gwt, apache-commons

I have problem that can be usefull for other if itt will be solved.
We upgraded our project to java ee 7 and file upload stopped working.

```
  @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException
    {

        try
        {
            DiskFileItemFactory fileItemFactory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
            ServletFileUpload fileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(fileItemFactory);
            fileUpload.setSizeMax(FILE_SIZE_LIMIT);

            List<FileItem> items = fileUpload.parseRequest(req);

            for (FileItem item : items)
            {
```

We are using gwt-uplaoder from moxiegroup.com
Simply List of FileItem-s is empty. I am checked post header, its OK.

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryT6rdf8NubigFhNZQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Filedata"; filename="2012-06-20 18.23.38.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryT6rdf8NubigFhNZQ
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="article_id"

1
```

Dont know where I can have problem. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed with removing @MultiPartconfig, because i am using apache commons. In glassfish 3 and EE6  it worked but in EE7 + glassfish 4 not.

Thanks for:
[Unable to use ApacheCommons for fileupload if I annotate the servlet with MultipartConfig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14443148/unable-to-use-apachecommons-for-fileupload-if-i-annotate-the-servlet-with-multip?rq=1)